# Multiple layouts for a single Jekyll collection?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I have a simple document like this:

```
---
title: My First Post
subtitle: My First Post
author: dan
tags: [fruit veggies]
---

My body content
```

My `_config.yml` has a typical:

```
defaults:
  # _docs
  - scope:
      path:         ""
      type:         docs
    values:
      layout:       doc
```

which outputs the correct HTML files etc.

I want to build a secondary HTML file (for a modal) using that same original document markdown file.

I made a new `modal.html` layout with my custom html etc and then added:

```
defaults:
  # _docs
  - scope:
      path:         ""
      type:         docs
    values:
      layout:       doc
  # _modal - partials for help modals
  - scope:
      path:         "modals"
      type:         docs
    values:
      layout:       modal
```

This works butShould this not work?  In my case it doesn't.  If I reverse the order I get the modal files but they are written in the docs folder.  Perhaps a precedence problem but I am at a loss to figure this out.

Comment: I did it using two different config files and then executing jekyll twice

It is not possible, at least until I know.

I did it using two different config files and executing jekyll build twice
jekyll build && jekyll --config _config.modal.yml build

Comment: I am going to try that - if that works I would accept that as an answer for the bounty (unless there is a more direct answer).

Comment: Hmm... this isn't working.  I want the `docs` collection to be rendered with the `modal` layout but in the `modal` directory vs. the `docs` folder.  I made a separate config file but they still overwrite each other - always in the `docs` folder.